# iTunes Error invalid IPA Through iTunes Sync weird error?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4, itunes, itunes-app

I have created one IPA file with right provision profile , after that i sync that IPA file from iTunes but it will getting error like ipa is not valid

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you generate the IPA, make sure you sign the app with the correct Code Signing Identity. that is in the last step of ipa generation before a save prompt appears, (if you are making ipa in Xcode > Product > Archive)

Comment: Yes also i have cross checked with build setting in that the code signing identity is the same as when i am going to make archive and select code signing identity